# Error testing function that navigates the user with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm testing my page, I'm calling a function that navigates the user to another page, but I'm getting the following error:

[image]

This is my test code:

```
it('must be navigated to the forgot password screen', async () => {
    const mockedNavigate = jest.fn();

    jest.mock('@react-navigation/native', () => {
      return {
        ...jest.requireActual('@react-navigation/native'),
        useNavigation: () => ({
          navigate: mockedNavigate,
        }),
      };
    });

    const { getByTestId } = render(<SignIn />, {
      wrapper: Providers,
    });

    fireEvent.press(getByTestId('forgot-password-button'));
    expect(mockedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

This is my page code:

```
import { RectButton } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export function SignIn() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  function forgotPasswordNavigate() {
    navigation.navigate('ForgotPassword')
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      
      <Form>

        <RectButton
          onPress={forgotPasswordNavigate}
          testID="forgot-password-button"
        >
          <ForgotPasswordText>Esqueci minha senha</ForgotPasswordText>
        </RectButton>

      </Form>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

I need my function to be called in this test so that my test passes

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Are you sure, that `getByTestId('forgot-password-button')` returns the correct element that pressing on it calls the callback function?

Comment: Yes, it is returning the element correctly.

Comment: Can you show the code for the `ForgotPasswordButton`?

Comment: It's that last block of code. It's inside my signIn page

Comment: I meant the code block, where you define the `ForgotPasswordButton` component.

Comment: It's a ```gesture-handle``` ```RectButton```, which comes from my styles. I'm using ```styled-components```

Comment: If you don't show the code, we can't help you. There has to be an implementation issue with the component.

Comment: I edited my code. This is the component I'm using